# Differences just List and List<Object> and List<?>

Tags: java, generics, erasure

According erasure concept I thought that

`List` and `List<Object>` are indentically but I noticed that

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();  
        List<Object> objList = strList; //error
        List objList = strList; //valid construction
        List<?> objList = strList; //valid construction
```

Comment: After erasure, not before.

Comment: The raw type is not safe and the generic type is. Working as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) However, to some extent your question answers itself since what you've discovered *is* the main difference. Using a raw type breaks type invariance.

Comment: There is a big difference, on `List<Object>` you force your list to use Object as class of each item, but on second items class declare in construction

Comment: @Farnabaz, ok. And third variant with **?** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Try adding to the `List<?>`. (It won't let you.)

Comment: @Radiodef is it only one difference?  Could you explain concept?

Comment: third variant same as second one, in this case you tell compiler that "I'm not sure about items class"

Comment: I'd recommend reading the question I linked to. It answers all of your questions.

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding specifically? There is not a 'simple' explanation you can just skim. In context of generic syntax these 3 kinds of lists have completely different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `List<?>` is a list with an unknown type. You cannot insert there
  because you cannot know what type you would be allowed to insert. It
  has a generic type (or not) but there is no way you can know it. If
  you get to insert something (typecasting the list first) you may be
  violating something so you should not.
- A `List<Object>` is a list where you can insert any object and when
  you get an item you only know (at first) that it is an object (and
  you already knew that).
- `List` is only allowed to be backward compatible (I think). Before
  Java 5 there were no generics. Java need to allow typecast between
  `List` and `List<Anything>` so the legacy code may work with modern code.

Answer (score 0):

`List<?>` is `generic` (`wildcard`), which means that it accepts from String to anything, that's why

```
List<?> objList = strList; //valid construction
```

while `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`(But String[] is in fact a subtype of Object[], that's one of the reasons why generics and arrays don't mix well). For `Object`

```
List<? extends Object> objList = strList; //valid construction
```

because `String` extends `Object`, here means anything extends to Object is accepted.

Answer (score -1):

**First explanation:**

If you define a List of Objects, than you state, that this List can contain anything you want. (This is some additional information you provide.)

If you define a List of Strings, than this is NOT a List of anything. It is a List of Strings.

A List of Strings is not the same as a List of Objects.

---

**Technical explanation:**

Let's say you have a class like this:

```
class Machine<T> {
    void process(T input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you then create an instance: `new Machine<String>()`, than the compiler knows, that your new object is ment to process Strings. It will fail if you want to make it process a Number, an Array or anything else.

If you create a more general machine, but calling `new Machine<Object>()`, than the compiler knows, that Strings, Numbers, Arrays and any kind of stuff can be processed by that machine.

The compiler will not allow you to cast the specific String-Machine (`new Machine<String>()`) to a general Object-Machine (`Machine<Object>`), because this would allow you to let it process Numbers, Arrays, etc. for what it was not meant for.